# Listview returns less children than the actual data feed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Is there a row limit on a listview?
I use a fragment to display a listview and I feed it 32 records, but when I implement a click it returns that it has only 12 rows; Here is the on click function:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    SELECTED_POSITION = position;
    if (listView.getChildCount() > 0) {
        listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                Color.parseColor("#036287"));
    }
}
```

What happens is that when listView.getChildAt(position) is executed and position is a number above 11 it throws an error. At the same time on the tablet I can see all rows, but they don't appear to be in the same listview as the first 12 records.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

---

Another issue is that when I change the color that way, I see several items selected, not 1. For example in a smaller scale to explain it

--

### Item 1

### Item 2

### Item 3

### Item 4

If the max position is 2, and I select Item 1, Item 1 and Item 3 lights up. If I select Item 2 - Item 2 and Item 4 lights up. If I select Item 3 - Item 1 and Item 3 lights up and so on.

It's really frustrating, because I can't get the view I need, because it seems that several views are contained at that position or in the variable view that is returned on list item click.

Comment: Have you used customlistview? If it is the Customlistview then tha problem would be in BaseAdapter class.

Comment: Yes, I've used a custom adapter, but how can I bypass this issue? If I select item above position 11, my program crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the data (a List<> I suppose) you use to feed the view has a size of 32, it doesn't mean the ListView has 32 child views.

The list view will only have the smallest number of views that are enough to fill the ListView (in your case it happens to be 11)

If you want to change the color of the views you either can manipulate the "view" parameter that you receive in the listener:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    view.setBackgroundColor([your color here]);
}
```

Or add the corresponding data to the data model you use to feed the adapter, and then call a notifyDataSetChanged on the list

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    YourObject yourObject = yourObjectList.get(position);
    yourObject.clicked = true;
}
```

then in the getView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
 [...]
 YourObject yourObject = yourObjectList.get(position);
 if(yourObject.clicked)
 {
     convertView.setBackgroundColor([your color here])
 }
 else
 {
     convertView.setBackgroundColor([your other color here])
 }
}
```

For your case I'd use the first option, but the second ono is useful in scenarios when you don't have a direct reference to the view (like if something happened in background)

Answer (score 0):

The data is probably fed to your `ListView` via an `Adapter`. For optimization purposes, a `Listview` only contains the items currently shown on the screen. It would be a waste of resources to render all the Views. Therefore, the item at the position specified might not be the same as the item you clicked.

The `onListItemCLick` contains a reference to the View object the used clicked on as argument, so my advise is to set the background color of the `View` given as parameter.

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#036287"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your getView() method, Just follow this way  and try

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendName);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

        holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D9D9D9"));
        holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#353535"));


    return convertView;
}
```

and

```
 class ViewHolder {

    TextView text;

    }
```

Comment: If it is useful for you just give me the upvote and accept it.